# Given a solution, find the constants $a,b,c,d$ for differential equation $y'''' + a y''' + b y'' + c y' +dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am given the differential equation $y^{\prime \prime \prime \prime} + a y^{\prime \prime \prime} + b y^{\prime\prime} + c y^\prime +dy = 0$ , where I must find the constants (which are real numbers) $a,b,c,d$. I am provided with the solution $y=4 te^{3 t}  - 6 e^{6 t}\sin (5 t)$.

I am at a loss as to what to do or how to approach such a problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, if there's a solution involving the sine, then there's one involving the cosine.

Comment: Please check that you did not forget a term in the provided solution (refer to Gerry Myerson's comment).

Comment: The provided solution only includes the sine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of the differential equation is

$p(t)= t^4+at^3+bt^2+ct+d$

Since $te^{3t}$ is a solution, $t=3$ is a zero of $p$ of order $2$

Since $e^{6t} \sin(5t)$ is a solution, $t=6+5i$ is a zero of $p$.

The coefficients of $p$ are real, hence $t=6-5i$ is a zero of $p$.

Conclusion: $p(t)=(t-3)^2(t-(6+5i))(t-(6-5i))$.

Your turn !

Comment: $te^t$ is not a solution and, even if it were, $t=0$ would not be a zero of $p$.  Otherwise looks good.

Comment: You are right ! Imade an edit.